# Getting this error message: dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Tags: database, error

I put my magento project on a linux server. First the error log messages shown up, but the folder var was missed. Then I created the var folder, I give it the 777 permissions and same with cache, report,session. In the error file from the report folder I got this message:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:65:"dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract";i:1;s:3543:"#0 /home/myfolder/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)
#1 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(MKleine_LanguageRoutes_Model_Resource_Languageroute))
#2 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('mk_languagerout...', Object(MKleine_LanguageRoutes_Model_Resource_Languageroute))
#3 /public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('mk_languagerout...', Object(MKleine_LanguageRoutes_Model_Resource_Languageroute))
#4 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('mk_languagerout...', Object(MKleine_LanguageRoutes_Model_Resource_Languageroute))
#5 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#6 /public_html/app/code/community/MKleine/LanguageRoutes/Model/Translation.php(150): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#7 /public_html/app/code/community/MKleine/LanguageRoutes/Model/Translation.php(129): MKleine_LanguageRoutes_Model_Translation->getRouteCollection(1)
#8 /public_html/app/code/community/MKleine/LanguageRoutes/Model/Translation.php(91): MKleine_LanguageRoutes_Model_Translation->translateToFront('install', 1)
#9 /public_html/app/code/community/MKleine/LanguageRoutes/Model/Core/Url.php(75): MKleine_LanguageRoutes_Model_Translation->translateRouteToFront('install')
#10 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(398): MKleine_LanguageRoutes_Model_Core_Url->getRouteFrontName()
#11 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(763): Mage_Core_Model_Url->getBaseUrl()
#12 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(995): Mage_Core_Model_Url->getRouteUrl('install', Array)
#13 /public_html/app/Mage.php(394): Mage_Core_Model_Url->getUrl('install', Array)
#14 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(711): Mage::getUrl('install', Array)
#15 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(689): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->setRedirectWithCookieCheck('install', Array)
#16 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(474): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirect('install')
#17 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(69): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#18 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#19 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#20 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

So what could cause this problem ? WHY ? and I do I solve it ?

Comment: Perhaps the solution in this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528617/after-migrating-the-production-magento-to-dev-server-dbmodel-read-resource-does

Comment: Please check your `ect/local.xml` file for right connection with your database. Do you have any extension installed? Or is it fresh magento. Which version is it?

Comment: So database connection it is ok. I am using 1.9.2 and I have some extensions installed

Comment: did this work on a windows machine before hand perhaps?

Comment: Actually @kaska post helped me I follow the instructions from that post and  I managed to solve it. Thx once again

Comment: You might not have override Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract properly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After I put the right database connection I also changed this line:

```
<disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
```

into this

```
<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
```

I gave recursively the 777 permission to the var folder using this command:

```
chmod -R 777 var
```

Comment: This solution is working fine

Answer (score 8):

in my case

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

solved the issue - **i changed my local.xml to a symlink though**

Answer (score 2):

in my case I needed just change the permissions of the var folder

```
chmod -R 777 var
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands and enjoy!

```
chown -R username:group var/
chmod -R 777 var/
rm -rf /var/cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is cache issue, you need to remove cache, flushi it using magerun or deleting cache folder 
rm -rf var/cache.

false this line just disables all modules that are under app/code/local/ folder.